# Powershell can't find class constructor?

Tags: powershell, class

My exception is happening in the foreach block of this code block:

```
    [void] Watch([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Directory, [string[]]$sFilters, [FSWatcherOptions]$Options) {
        foreach($sFilter in $sFilters) {
            $FSEventData = [FSEventData]::new($Directory, $sFilter, $Options)
            ...
        }
    }
```

Here's the dependencies, in the same script, 80-ish lines above the exception.

```
enum FSWatcherOptions {
    Recurse = 1
}
class FSEventData : IComparable, IEquatable[Object] {
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Watched
    [string]$sFilter
    [FSWatcherOptions]$Options

    FSEventData()  {
        param {
            [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Watched,
            [string]$sFilter,
            [FSWatcherOptions]$Options
        }
        $this.Watched = Watched
        $this.sFilter = sFilter
        $this.Options = Options
    }
    [string] ToString() {
        return "Watched:$($this.Watched.FullName)Filter:$($this.sFilter)Options:$($this.Options.ToString())"
    }
    [FSEventData] Clone() {
        return [FSEventData]::new($this.Watched, $this.sFilter, $this.Options)
    }
    hidden [int] CompareWatched([FSEventData]$that) {
        [int] $out = 0
        if ($this.Watched -gt $that.Watched) {$out =  1}
        if ($this.Watched -lt $that.Watched) {$out = -1}
        return $out
    }
    hidden [int] CompareFilter ([FSEventData]$that) {
        [int] $out = 0
        if ($this.sFilter -gt $that.sFiler) {$out =  1}
        if ($this.sFilter -lt $that.sFiler) {$out = -1}
        return $out
    }
    hidden [int] CompareOptions([FSEventData]$that) {
        [int] $out = 0
        if ($this.Options -gt $that.Options) {$out =  1}
        if ($this.Options -lt $that.Options) {$out = -1}
        return $out
    }
    [int] CompareTo($that) {
        If (-Not($that -is [FSEventData])) {
            Throw "Not Comparable!!"
        }
        [int]$out = 0
        $out = $this.CompareWatched([FSEventData]$that)
        if ($out -eq 0) {$out = $this.CompareFilter}
        if ($out -eq 0) {$out = $this.CompareOptions}
        return $out
    }
    [bool] Equals  ($that) {
        If (-Not($that -is [FSEventData])) {
            Throw "Not Equatable!!"
        }
        return {
            $this.Watched -eq $that.Watched -and
            $this.sFilter -eq $that.sFilter -and
            $this.Options -eq $that.Options
        }
    }
}
```

The IComparable and IEquatable methods included for debugging purposes. The exception I receive is :

```
Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "3".
At X:\FFFF\FileSystemEventProcessor.ps1:95 char:13
+             $FSEventData = [FSEventData]::new($Directory, $filter, $O ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

What am I missing here because the code looks fine, and was working until my last edit yesterday. I've spent a few hours on trying to feret out what the problem is, but ultimately my searches came up dry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors in your `.ctor`. There is no such thing as a `param { ... }` syntax in [PowerShell Class Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2#constructor). Then, the use of `Watched`, `sFilter` and `Options` as if they were commands which will end throwing a [CommandNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandnotfoundexception?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) if you were instantiating the class with no `.ctor` arguments.

To fix that error, change the `.ctor` definition from:

```bash
FSEventData() {
    param {
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] $Watched,
        [string] $sFilter,
        [FSWatcherOptions] $Options
    }
    $this.Watched = Watched
    $this.sFilter = sFilter
    $this.Options = Options
}
```

To (notice the removal of `param { ... }` and addition of the arguments to your `.ctor`):

```bash
FSEventData(
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] $Watched,
    [string] $sFilter,
    [FSWatcherOptions] $Options
) {
    $this.Watched = $Watched
    $this.sFilter = $sFilter
    $this.Options = $Options
}
```

Then you can instantiate `FSEventData` without issues:

```bash
[FSEventData]::new((Get-Item .), 'foo', [FSWatcherOptions]::Recurse)

# Watched                sFilter Options
# -------                ------- -------
# C:\User\Documents\pwsh foo     Recurse
```

Comment: Making this alteration did not alter behavior, sorry.

Comment: @JaazCole you need to provide the definition for the other class then.

Comment: Added, it's just an enum.

Comment: @JaazCole I meant the class that has the `[void] Watch([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Directory, [string[]]$sFilters, [FSWatcherOptions]$Options)` signature defined.

Comment: Definition Included.

Comment: This script was being run by a class which loaded a module. (not detailed above) The module being unloaded before the next try allowed for a new exception to emerge. Thanks for the answer, I'll take it from here.

Comment: @JaazCole I was thinking that might have been your problem. Remember when working with classes in a module, use `Import-Module -Force` (`-Force` will unload and re-load for you).